# How to convert Binary to String in scala glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, aws-glue

```scala
root
|-- person_id_enc: binary
|-- creation_set_id_enc: binary
|-- device_serial_num_enc: binary
|-- device_snapshot_id_enc: binary
|-- device_id_enc: binary
```

I'm getting above Dataframe schema as binary data type in AWS scala glue & I want to convert this schema into string datatype as below in the form of dataframe.

Expected dataframe :

```scala
root
|-- creation_set_id_enc: string
|-- device_serial_num_enc: string
|-- device_snapshot_id_enc: string
|-- device_id_enc: string
```

```scala
val fieldEnc: BinaryNode = rec.getFieldNode(commItm.get(0).toString).get.asInstanceOf[BinaryNode]
                  rec.addField(commItm.get(0).toString, StringNode(BaseEncoding.base64().encode(fieldEnc.value)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this by using resolveChoice method in dataframe like below -

```
val extraDroppedDyf_modified  = extraDroppedDyf.resolveChoice(specs = Seq(("creation_set_id_enc", "cast:String"),("device_serial_num_enc", "cast:String"),("device_snapshot_id_enc", "cast:String"),("device_id_enc", "cast:String")))
```

- Now you can print the schema.. This works for me

  ```
  extraDroppedDyf_modified.printSchema()

  O/P -- 

  root
  |-- creation_set_id_enc: string
  |-- device_serial_num_enc: string
  |-- device_snapshot_id_enc: string
  |-- device_id_enc: string
  ```